# dos2unix overwriting original file owner name

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to convert a file `test.txt` using `dos2unix`, but when i do so the original file owner `demo` is overwritten by my user `test` as shown below.

`-rwxrwxr-x   1 demo   gpappl       382 Feb 27 02:29 test.txt`

`>dos2unix test.txt test.txt`

`>ls -lrt`

`total 8`

`-rw-r--r--   1 test   gpappl       382 Feb 27 02:36 test.txt`

Can you one help me how can i not overwrite owner using dos2unix?

Comment: Try passing -o to force old file mode

Comment: If you are ok to use(though I can't replicate your problem since I don't have dos2unix utility with me), you could use alternative to remove control M characters from file then do like: `tr -d < Input_file > temp &&  mv temp Input_file` once?

Comment: `tr` command also didn't help me much as at the end it's creating file with my user id only i.e. temp file :-(

Comment: `-o` option also didn't work for me

Comment: Which version of dos2unix are you using? Try a new version.

Comment: you can change back the owner name `chown demo test.txt`